# Can I install different softwares into one Aws EC2 virtual machine?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to ask a question as I'm new to AWS.

At one instance of Ubuntu EC2 I installed InfluxDB and it is running so I want to know if I can install Node.js on that same instance? Would my node.js installation affect InfluxDB?

Basically, I want to run a background nodejs script that will be live forever, to insert data to InfluxDB from a server.

Would I need to launch a separate virtual machine to run that script OR it will be on that same virtual machine?

Comment: You can install basically whatever you want.

Comment: That's the answer I want to hear . Thanks @luk2302

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, you can install and run any software in a single EC2 instance. The only limit is the underlying resource, meaning whether the instance has sufficient memory, CPU, disk I/O or network bandwidth to run all of them.

Practically, any decisions you make will have trade-offs and it's always good for you to be aware of them.

In your case, I can give you some pros and cons of the 2 approaches

**Same-instance installation**

- Pros: easy to configure as your script is in the same instance with your InfluxDB. Also , if your NodeJS script has a small resource footprint, then this approach is possibly cheaper as well.
- Cons: if you are running a cluster of multiple InfluxDB instances, having multiple copies of a NodeJS script in all of your InfluxDB instances will make it hard to maintain, deploy, update and monitor those instances.

This approach is only recommended if you are running single-node InfluxDB.

---

**Dedicated installation**

- Pros: easy to scale up. easy to manage, deploy and update. better availability.

You can have a dedicated cluster of InfluxDB and another much smaller cluster of your NodeJS scripts.

This separation provides you a more reliable cluster for InfluxDB, as the frequency that you update your NodeJS script is usually higher than you update your InfluxDB software. Having a dedicated NodeJS cluster gives you peace of mind that even if your script has a critical bug, your InfluxDB cluster is still running fine.

- Cons: harder to configure. You also need to deal with the distributed nature of your system, as your script is now hosted in different instances of your InfluxDB. Also, this approach is more expensive as well.

You should consider this approach if you are running InfluxDB cluster.

Comment: Thanks @gokien for the explanation. I really want to know in-depth so everything will be fine in the future. Your answer clears the way for me.

Comment: np @AhsanDanish. please consider accepting the answer if it helps. thanks

Comment: Oh I didn't know that. Anyway I accepted the answer.